# Open link new window (not tab) with JavaScript without typing the URL twice?

Tags: javascript

It's possible make a link open in a new window (not tab) with this:

```
<a href="print.html"  onclick="window.open('print.html', 'newwindow', 'width=300, height=250'); return false;"> Print</a>
```

Is it possible to modify this slightly so that the JavaScript looks at the href of the link so you don't have to write it out twice in the code?

Comment: @DavidSpence I don't think so. This asks specifically about in an `<a>` element, and using its `href`.

Comment: FYI this has nothing to do with jQuery, so i removed that tag.

Comment: It has nothing to do with 'new windows (not tabs)' either; it's "how do I pass a property of the node into an event-handling function?" isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="print.html"  onclick="window.open(this.href, 'newwindow', 'width=300, height=250'); return false;"> Print</a>
```

`this.href` is a reference to the `href` attribute of the element when in the `onclick` handler.